# Is this water pressure tank gauge working?

Tags: water-pressure

I feel like our pressure tank is running constantly lately.  I just took a look at it and am puzzled by the gauge on the side.  This isn't zero - it's maxed out.  Broken?  ..or is there a bomb growing in my basement?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That gauge is toast, it needs to be replaced.

Comment: I agree it's broken, your pressure switch controls the pressure if you had that much pressure your faucets , and toilets would probably be leaking.